# Wildfly 15 and higher : class name clashes with package name

Tags: java, jar, wildfly, classloader, conflict

I'm having this structure in one of the external jars in the lib directory of WEB-INF inside a deployed war file :

```
jar
 |
  MyPackage
 |
  MyPackage.class
 |
```

So, the class name also exists as a package name resulting in a compilation error when I invoke the class.

This error does not occur in Wildfly 11.
Any suggestion to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> "Any suggestion to avoid this problem?"

Simply don't do it.  Rename the class or the package.

Note that if the code author had followed the Java style rules, this would not occur.  The style rules say that a class name should start with an upper-case letter and a package name should be all lower-case.  If everyone followed the rules, this collision could not arise.

(Or ... if this is not your code, lodge a bug report to get the code fault in relevant code fixed.)